# Passing event handler as props in React Typescirpt

Tags: javascript, react-typescript

I'm trying to pass an event handler from a parent component to a child. the point is to change the state of the parent when user clicks on child component.
the problem is it throws an error as below:

```
 /*
    (property) onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<Element>
     Type '{ onClick: MouseEventHandler<Element>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
     Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
 */
```

the Parent Component:

```
export default function Card(): JSX.Element {
  const [clear, setClear] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleClick:React.MouseEventHandler = (): void => {
    setClear(!clear);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title>5 birthdays today</Title>
      {clear ? "" : list}
      <Button onClick={handleClick} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

The child:

```
interface Props {
  handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<Element>;
}

export default function Button({ handleClick }: Props): JSX.Element {
  return <Btn onClick={handleClick}>Clear All</Btn>;
}
```

I did looked up for the solution in the [React Typescript stylesheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/)

but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message gives You the hint:

> Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> Props'

You need to add the proper type to the child prop types. Try this

```
interface Props {
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement
}
```

You need to inform TS that Your child component expects the `onCLick` prop. In Your case TS is waiting for the `handleClick` prop which is incorrect because the props name is "onCLick"

Comment: No problem  :) If my comment helped, consider marking it as an accepted answer. Cheers!